# How Do I see the "Big Picture" of my small part in a company?

Tags: job-change, new-job, learning

I recently started a new job, which is technically challenging.  Because of this, it is very easy for me to get caught up on small details, sometimes missing the big picture behind what's going on.

How do I balance learning about the details of work and trying to understand "the big picture" with practically getting things done for my boss?

I am concerned it will take quite some time for me to have a deep understanding of the technical aspects of my new job, and I want to be productive in the meantime.  How do I balance overcoming the learning curve and understanding the big picture with actually getting things done?

Answer (score 12):

### Context is King

Bob is a cog-maker in a widget manufacturer. He wants to make the best cog possible. He focuses on the intricacies of how best to machine the cog teeth, the best steel to create a durable cog, and the best material to use for a highly-polished attractive cog. Indeed, his cogs are a piece of work.

Six months later Bob is out of work. Turns out that the widget doesn't actually need cogs, and bearings are a better solution. Since Bob only knows how to make cogs, he isn't much use creating bearings, since all the knowledge was so focused on technical details and not actual functionality in the larger widget.

Don't be Bob. Understand what you're making and how it fits in with the larger whole.

### The Scope of Context

> *At WidgetCorp, we've been creating the world's most advanced widgets for 130 years. As technology has developed, so have our widgets, which
>   is why we are such a titan of the widget industry. Of course, that
>   means our widgets have gotten a lot more complicated, so we have to
>   break down the process in to more easily understandable parts. Each
>   widget is composed of four main sprockets, and each sprocket contains
>   a lot of parts of its own.*

Nobody (and I mean nobody) can understand how to make a 787 when they join Boeing. Modern technology (be it hardware or software) is too complex to understand each portion of from the start. Each portion of the process is broken down to a point where an individual can contribute, and then those portions are pieced together in to parts, which are put together in to components, which are put together in to an airplane (or program).

### The Context Learning Curve

I recommend a two-pronged approach to getting context.

The first is to understand the most macro level -- how does your customer use the product, what is the purpose? This will allow you to see things from the perspective of the person paying money, and give you a good low-level understanding of what the goals of the company are.

The second is to understand the most micro level -- how your part works, and the immediate things it ties in to. At the end of the day you have to be able to get your job done, and you will become much better at that if you understand how your part fits in with the surrounding components.

Let's say you work for DeLorean making [carburetors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carburetor).

The macro is understanding that people want a sporty car that can go 88 miles per hour so it can travel through time.

On your end you are making a device that mixes fuel and air so that the engine can run more efficiently. You need to understand how the air gets in, how the fuel gets in, and where the mixture of fuel and air goes. This will let you make a better carburetor, and allow your company to meet its goals of producing a sporty car that can go 88 miles per hour.

### Context Brings Better Understanding

Once you understand the carburetor and where things go, you will get a better concept of how the engine works. You will get great knowledge of the carburetor itself, but also a passing amount of knowledge on the requirements and challenges of the processes that come before and after. This will make you an expert in the fuel system. Once you understand the fuel system on a very specific level, you can extend that knowledge to understanding how fuel affects engine efficiency, and ways to improve surrounding systems by looking one step higher.

Eventually you will understand all the components on a macro level, and many components on a micro level. This will make you be able to manage the production of a DeLorean even if you can't build each part by hand, because you know how each system interacts, and the major things to focus on for each. The people doing the specifics and work out the smaller interactions within each system just like you did when working on the carburetor.

### Practical Application

1. **Focus on your cog** Your job is to make the cog. Make sure you can do that. That should be your first priority
2. **Ask questions** When making your cog, you will be given specifications for how it connects to other cogs. Talk to the people who design the cogs before and after. Listen to them talk about their work (almost everyone loves talking about what they do).
3. **Be patient** You won't understand everything at once, but as you slowly gain more information on a variety of systems, you will surprise yourself at how much you actually know, and how much more you start to pick up on. Your work on your own cog will improve, as will your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ideas I'd consider here:

1. What are the main principles about this work place?  This is a question worth asking of various people and seeing what is the culture of the place.  Is it a place where authorization is required in triplicate to do anything or do people just do whatever seems right without getting approvals all the time?
2. Ask for what is to be done and what limits are there on the work.  The key here is to get an idea of what changes are you making as well as at a high level understand some aspects of the big picture that will become more clear as you get things done and get used to how things flow in that company.
3. Be prepared to ask for feedback regularly so that you can get an idea of how well are you doing or not doing in your role.

In most new roles, the learning curve is par for the course.  The key is being able to get tangible results of bugs fixed, features implemented, and helping keep a team on track, as some of the minor details will get picked up indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation and it gets very frustrating when people are talking about terms specific to their company without explaining. It's like a new language.
Therefore treat it as learning a new language.
-prioritize what's most important and make sure you're getting your work done.
-apply yourself in meetings and with your co-workers
-be humble and teachable; don't be afraid to ask questions or for help. (people love feeling needed and useful. so unless they're stressed out trying to get their own stuff done, they will most likely take the time to walk through anything you need. If you don't speak up you or think you can do it yourself you're going to struggle and have a harder time).

This is what I've been doing and it still is frustrating but everyone knows and understands I'm new and don't know everything. Milk that cause soon they'll expect that you know enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem faced by many. So first, dont worry, your not the only one wearing such shoes. Dont let go off the habit of getting stuck on the small details. As you will learn, this is one of the most important things a software engineer should do. To shorten the time of your learning curve, you have to invest in training yourself, even if it means giving up on personal time.  
To get the big picture, it takes time. Have you read all different documents pertaining to your project ? You need to be able to put yourself in the shoes of your client (or your company, in case you are a product company) to *see* and *know* what business problems are being solved. You need to have a handle on the big picture, but need not necessarily be hung up on it. 
 
 You just have to hang in there. I am sure you will have specific documents pertaining to the tasks you are given. Deliver efficient code on time and  stick to the specs,  and with time the pieces of the puzzle will fall in place.